# JetBrains Rider to stop opening diff tab on navigation

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I am a huge fan of JetBrains Rider it is really adaptable to the tastes of most devs. I could not find settings to remove an annoyance from a specific navigation function.

Navigating on the tree view of the git changes opens up a new tab to show the selected file differences, this can also be triggered via shortcuts. It is really annoying to have to close it every time I tab out and back into Rider.

The file differences are also displayed besides the git navigation tree, so displaying a new tab just gets in the way.

Is there a configuration to disable the automatic display of this diff on a new tab?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Following [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2019/11/18/new-way-commit-introducing-commit-repository-tool-windows-rider-2019-3-eap/) from JetBrains I did what they commended here:

> After opening a project, press shift shift (Search Everywhere) and
> search for “Registry”. Next, start typing any of the following three
> switches to enable or disable things:
>
> ```
> show.diff.preview.as.editor.tab – toggles the in-editor diff preview
> ```

I then disabled the `show.diff.preview.as.editor.tab` setting.

The diff tab no longer appeared

For newer versions, the setting is now `show.diff.preview.as.editor.tab.with.single.click`

Comment: disabling the "show.diff.preview.as.editor.tab" did it! thank you very much! could you please re-write your answer as a step by step instruction on how to disable this param (it is in your link). I will accept your answer once this is done

Comment: The setting is now called `show.diff.preview.as.editor.tab.with.single.click`.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work anymore. Rider 2021.2

Comment: @HankScorpio: works fine for 2021.3. The original behavior renders the Commits windows unusable for me, it's annoying and distracting as hell. I know exactly what I'm doing and don't need diff most of the time.

Answer (score 15):

It's actually quite easy to do that via the commit settings menu in 2022.2. Just click on the cog wheel and deselect "Show Diff Preview on Single Click".

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This! It works and is so simple. Rider 2022.3